# same code but different results using gin + go-template

Tags: html, go, go-templates, go-gin

**Basic information**

- Go version: go1.4.2 darwin/amd64
- Operating System: Mac OS X 10.10.5

I'm working on a small Web project written based on **go** and **gin**. Here is my golang code. After running `go run test.go` we have a web server, which is listening on 8089.

**Golang test.go**

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
import "net/http"

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*")
    router.GET("/index", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{
            "scheme": "http",
            "domain": "meican.loc",
        })
    })
    router.Run(":8089") // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8089
}
```

The html code generated in back-end should contain a template used by front-end javascript engine (Let's say Angular.js).

So the template code is in `script` tag, just like this:

**Part of templates/index.html**

```
<script type="text/template" charset="utf-8">
  <div data="{{.scheme}}://{{.domain}}/qr"></div>
  <div data="{{.scheme}}://{{.domain}}/qr"></div> <!-- problem here -->
</script>
```

When `{{.domain}}` is used at the second time, I got different result. I refreshed the browser and checked out the source code. Then I got this:

**Browser source code result**

```
<script type="text/template" charset="utf-8">
  <div data="http://meican.loc/qr"></div>
  <div data="http://"meican.loc"/qr"></div>  <!-- problems here -->
</script>
```

The second `div` has 2 extra double quotes.

Why this happens? And how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Go, and has been [slated to be fixed in 1.7](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/14336/) as of March 2016 (Also [partially addressed](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/14335/) in 1.6)